# Why isn't the Spring Statemachine project listed on the home page of the website?

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

I recently thought of deep-diving into the various Spring projects, after seeing first-hand the tremendous utility provided to a project in my workplace. We used the Spring [Statemachine](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/pdf/spring-statemachine-reference.pdf) project to implement a shopping cart lifecycle. This was a suggestion made by one of my colleagues while looking up code samples to implement the [State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) in Java. Additionally, I've independently used [Spring for Android](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/) to implement my first Android App.

However, on visiting the Spring homepage, I wasn't able to see the Spring Statemachine project listed there. Additionally, it wasn't mentioned in the [offline documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/pdf/spring-framework-reference.pdf), either, despite there being a [copy of the same](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/pdf/spring-statemachine-reference.pdf).

I have two questions from this:

1. Where could one find a full listing of all the various projects provided by Spring? I tried consulting their Github page, but (for example) a filter on repos by "Kafka" returned [two](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka) [different](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka) repos (FYI, the [project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/) redirects to the second URL). I was hoping for a comprehensive source like the [Wikipedia page on all Apache projects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apache_Software_Foundation_projects)
2. Why isn't the Statemachine project listed on the homepage? Is there some criteria which results in some projects being listed there, and some not?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on its way to the main projects page as not long ago it was still kept in `incubation`. We're just waiting for a logo.

You generally see all projects which have created their own page in `docs->Reference Documentation` [reference docs](https://spring.io/docs/reference)